# Customize score of documents using plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to customize the score of documents for search. The problem is that I need to provide parameters to the search and use a third-party library to process the new scores.

The use case is to boost the score if the location of the element is within provided areas (geojson as parameter of the query). For example, if the element is within area #1, the element score is boosted with value `a` and `b` for area #2, ...

Is a rescore plugin the best approach? See https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins/examples/rescore.

Are there other approaches?

I'm using Elasticsearch 7.

Thanks for your help!
Thierry

Comment: Are the "custom" scores available at indexing time? Basically, if you can add this "logic/score" while indexing, you can use the indexed field to influence the score

Comment: Thanks for the comment! In fact, no it's at the search time only. The use case is to boost the score if the location of the element is within provided areas (geojson)...

Comment: I added more details of the use case in the description...

Comment: Got it. How is the `location` stored in the indexed document? Based on use case, I thought of [Geo Location Search](https://www.elastic.co/blog/geo-location-and-search)

Comment: Thanks but it's not exactly what I'm trying to do... I'm trying to implement score boosting if elements are in polygons...

Comment: These polygons are provided within the query...

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: Cool, have you investigated the [`script_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html) (formerly known as [`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html))?

Comment: Yes but it's not what I exactly need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like below

Mapping:

```
    "mappings": {
        "properties" : {
            "pin" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
```

Query: In function score different functions can be added with different geo-polygon and respective weights

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "geo_polygon": {
              "pin": {
                "points": [
                  {
                    "lat": 40,
                    "lon": -70
                  },
                  {
                    "lat": 42,
                    "lon": -74
                  },
                  {
                    "lat": 20,
                    "lon": -90
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "geo_polygon": {
              "pin": {
                "points": [
                  {
                    "lat": 10,
                    "lon": -10
                  },
                  {
                    "lat": 12,
                    "lon": -14
                  },
                  {
                    "lat": 5,
                    "lon": -25
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "location",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "rhn8f20BIb7c4jbYhr3Z",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "pin" : {
            "lat" : 40.73,
            "lon" : -74.1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "location",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "rxn8f20BIb7c4jbYz709",
        "_score" : 3.0,     ---> score same as assigned weight
        "_source" : {
          "pin" : {
            "lat" : 40.717,
            "lon" : -73.99
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "location",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "CI25gG0BsKuS2MwMKcVU",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "pin" : {
            "lat" : 10.717,
            "lon" : -13.99
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Yes looks like to what I'm looking for. Thanks! Is it possible to boost score with this approach? I mean the current score is multiply (or something else) if in the polygon...

Comment: you can use Boost for the whole query. Within functions you can use weight. Filter queries will have  default score 1 * weight

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I looked for :-)

Comment: Glad could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a plugin might be the solution, but there is not much documentation available on writing a plugin.

I think the main drawback writing a plugin is keeping it up to date. You will have to rebuild your plugin for each change of elasticsearch version (including minor version changes). Rebuilding is ok, but the internal API is changing often so a simple update might lead to update your plugin as well.

Maybe another solution could be to implement the algorithm using painless ?

Comment: The jaspreet chahal's answer is what I looked for and doesn't use plugin :-) Thanks for taking time to post an answer! Really appreciate!